# How to make a slideshow with only a timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

I'm trying to make a slideshow for a webpage with only a timer, since i do not yet understand how jQuery works. I have the first part done already, but I don't know how to make the images reappear after the cycle is complete.

here is my code

```js
function Timer1(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('image1')[0].style.visibility = "hidden"; 
}
    setTimeout(Timer1,3000);

function Timer2(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('image2')[0].style.visibility = "hidden"; 
}
    setTimeout(Timer2,6000);
 
function Timer3(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('image3')[0].style.visibility = "hidden"; 
}
    setTimeout(Timer3,9000);

function Timer4(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('image4')[0].style.visibility = "hidden"; 
}
    setTimeout(Timer4,12000);
 
function Timer5(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('image5')[0].style.visibility = "hidden"; 
}
    setTimeout(Timer5,15000);
```

```html
<div class="slide1">
<img class="image1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/2000px-Smiley.svg.png" style="width:400px;height:300px;position:absolute;top:250px;left:100px;z-index:5;">
  </div>

<div class="slide1">
<img class="image2" src="http://science-all.com/images/wallpapers/pictures-of-happy-faces/pictures-of-happy-faces-14.jpg" style="width:400px;height:300px;position:absolute;top:250px;left:100px;z-index:5;">
  </div>

<div class="slide3">
<img class="image1" src="http://science-all.com/images/wallpapers/pictures-of-happy-faces/pictures-of-happy-faces-13.gif" style="width:400px;height:300px;position:absolute;top:250px;left:100px;z-index:5;">
  </div>

<div class="slide1">
<img class="image4" src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/aTe/Mng/aTeMngqT4.jpeg" style="width:400px;height:300px;position:absolute;top:250px;left:100px;z-index:5;">
  </div>

<div class="slide5">
<img class="image5" src="http://science-all.com/images/wallpapers/pictures-of-happy-faces/pictures-of-happy-faces-19.jpg" style="width:400px;height:300px;position:absolute;top:250px;left:100px;z-index:5;">
  </div>
```

I have images from my computer but i substituted web links here.
I would like it to be where once the cycle completes itself it starts over.
thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use available jquery sliders (there are hundreds of it) instead of creating it yourself?

Comment: May I suggest `.setInterval()` instead/

Comment: Or .setTimeout() in a self-calling function, with a pause state detection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a good first try, and doing something like this is a great way to learn! You could definitely stand to generalize your code quite a bit, your functions are pretty much all doing the same thing, just with a different class (*side note*: an `id` probably makes more sense in this case, since it's not generic) - therefore the variable should made into an argument and you should remove all but one function.

```
function Timer(className){
    document.querySelector('.' + className).style.visibility = "hidden"; 
}
```

Having said that, it might make more sense to use a single time interval and work on the collection of images, rather than individual ones (that way you can add more images without having to update your code). Here is a basic idea of how you could approach that:

Update your HTML to use a generic class "slide":

```
<div class="slide">
   <img class="image1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/2000px-Smiley.svg.png" style="width:400px;height:300px;position:absolute;top:250px;left:100px;z-index:5;">
</div>

<div class="slide">
   <img class="image2" src="http://science-all.com/images/wallpapers/pictures-of-happy-faces/pictures-of-happy-faces-14.jpg" style="width:400px;height:300px;position:absolute;top:250px;left:100px;z-index:5;">
</div>

<div class="slide">
  <img class="image1" src="http://science-all.com/images/wallpapers/pictures-of-happy-faces/pictures-of-happy-faces-13.gif" style="width:400px;height:300px;position:absolute;top:250px;left:100px;z-index:5;">
</div>

<div class="slide">
  <img class="image4" src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/aTe/Mng/aTeMngqT4.jpeg" style="width:400px;height:300px;position:absolute;top:250px;left:100px;z-index:5;">
</div>

<div class="slide">
  <img class="image5" src="http://science-all.com/images/wallpapers/pictures-of-happy-faces/pictures-of-happy-faces-19.jpg" style="width:400px;height:300px;position:absolute;top:250px;left:100px;z-index:5;">
</div>
```

Create a function called `slideshow` that will initialize:

```
function slideshow() {
   // GOALS:
   //  1. Get a reference to all slides (e.g. slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slides'))
   //  2. Set an index that will track which one is visible (start at 1)
   //  3. Make first slide (index-1) visible
   //  3. Start the interval (e.g. setInterval(showNextSlideThenUpdateIndex, 300))

   // super verbosely named for clarity
   function showNextSlideThenUpdateIndex() {
       // GOALS:
       //   1. if index == 0, set slides[slides.length-1] visibility to hidden,
       //      otherwise, set slides[index-1] to hidden
       //   2. set slides[index] to visible
       //   3. increment index or set to 0 if index === slides.length
   }
}
```

Here is an example:

```js
function slideshow() {
  var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
  var index = 1;
  var wait = 300;

  slides[index-1].style.visibility = 'visible';
  
  setInterval(showNextSlideThenUpdateIndex, wait);

  function showNextSlideThenUpdateIndex() {
    slides[index].style.visibility = 'visible';
    
    if (index === 0) {
      slides[slides.length-1].style.visibility = 'hidden';
      index++;
    } else if (index === slides.length-1) {
      // reset index to start slideshow over
      slides[index - 1].style.visibility = 'hidden';
      index = 0;
    } else {
      slides[index-1].style.visibility = 'hidden';
      index++;
    }
  }
}

slideshow();
```

```css
.slide {
  visibility: hidden;  
}
```

```html
    <div class="slide">
       <img class="image1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/2000px-Smiley.svg.png" style="width:400px;height:300px;position:absolute;top:250px;left:100px;z-index:5;">
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
       <img class="image2" src="http://science-all.com/images/wallpapers/pictures-of-happy-faces/pictures-of-happy-faces-14.jpg" style="width:400px;height:300px;position:absolute;top:250px;left:100px;z-index:5;">
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <img class="image1" src="http://science-all.com/images/wallpapers/pictures-of-happy-faces/pictures-of-happy-faces-13.gif" style="width:400px;height:300px;position:absolute;top:250px;left:100px;z-index:5;">
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <img class="image4" src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/aTe/Mng/aTeMngqT4.jpeg" style="width:400px;height:300px;position:absolute;top:250px;left:100px;z-index:5;">
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <img class="image5" src="http://science-all.com/images/wallpapers/pictures-of-happy-faces/pictures-of-happy-faces-19.jpg" style="width:400px;height:300px;position:absolute;top:250px;left:100px;z-index:5;">
    </div>
```

This is far from perfect, but hopefully helps you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

```
// configure your slides and durations here
var slides = [{ name: "image1", duration: 3000 }, { name: "image2", duration: 6000 }], currentIndex = 0, current = slides[currentIndex];

function changeSlide() {
  document.getElementsByClassName(current.name)[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
  currentIndex++;
  if (currentIndex >= slides.length) { currentIndex = 0; }
  current = slides[currentIndex];
  setTimeout(changeSlide, current.duration);
}

// starts the whole thing off
setTimeout(changeSlide, current.duration);
```

This can be tightened up and made smarter and whatnot, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

One more convenient way for doing this can be :
Hide all your image, i.e with a css class, .hidden, but keep the first visible.

When the page has loaded,call a function, let's name it myslide(). This function has to look for the current displayed image, hide it, then look for the next (or the first) image to display it. When the last image is hidden, the newt one can't be shown, so we need to check for this case, and display the image.

Here is a jQuery version. Once written, it should be easy to understand.

```js
window.onload=setTimeout(myslide,3000);
function myslide()
{
//we use the image that is not hidden
  img=$(".slide:not(.hidden)");
  img.addClass("hidden");
  
  if (img.is('.slide:last')) 
    $("#container .slide:first").removeClass("hidden");
  else 
    img.next( ".slide" ).removeClass("hidden");

setTimeout(myslide,3000);
}
```

```css
.hidden{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'>
<div class="slide">
<img class="image1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/2000px-Smiley.svg.png" style="width:400px;height:300px;position:absolute;top:250px;left:100px;z-index:5;">
  </div>

<div class="slide">
<img class="image2" src="http://science-all.com/images/wallpapers/pictures-of-happy-faces/pictures-of-happy-faces-14.jpg" style="width:400px;height:300px;position:absolute;top:250px;left:100px;z-index:5;">
  </div>

<div class="slide">
<img class="image1" src="http://science-all.com/images/wallpapers/pictures-of-happy-faces/pictures-of-happy-faces-13.gif" style="width:400px;height:300px;position:absolute;top:250px;left:100px;z-index:5;">
  </div>

<div class="slide">
<img class="image4" src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/aTe/Mng/aTeMngqT4.jpeg" style="width:400px;height:300px;position:absolute;top:250px;left:100px;z-index:5;">
  </div>

<div class="slide">
<img class="image5" src="http://science-all.com/images/wallpapers/pictures-of-happy-faces/pictures-of-happy-faces-19.jpg" style="width:400px;height:300px;position:absolute;top:250px;left:100px;z-index:5;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add html code as it
2. jQuery code: you have just add this set interval function on document ready it will work fine.

---

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
     setInterval(function() {
         $('#slideshow > div:first')
             .fadeOut(1000)
             .next()
             .fadeIn(1000)
             .end()
             .appendTo('#slideshow');
     }, 3000);
 });
```